Why are push constant ranges exclusive to specific shader stages in Vulkan?
Let's say I have two floats that I want to pass to the device as push constants. I use one exclusively in the vertex shader and the other exclusively in the fragment shader. I declare the push constant range [0, 4) with vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eVertex and the range [4, 8) with vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eFragment. In every frame, I push data for both.
Here are my questions:

Why do I have to tell the API in which shader stage a range is used? What does the driver/the device do with this information?
If I decided to declare all of my push constants to be usable by all shader stages by default (i.e. make a single large range with all shader stage flags set), would I encounter negative effects?


This depends on how "push constants" are implemented in the particular GPU. If each shader stage has different memory storage for push constant data, then a change to a range that impacts both stages will require uploading the data for each impacted stages.
Or it might not, depending on how it gets implemented.
That being said, push constant data is extremely small, and the size of data you're dealing with is even smaller than that. And if you're changing both values at the same time anyway, both shaders will need to upload something to get started. So it probably won't matter if that something happens to come from the same cache line as a different stage.
Overall, I would hold off on micro-optimizations like these unless you have clear performance metrics on the target architectures that this is a problem.
